# Tap Gestures to Dismiss UITextField with TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with a UITextField that performs some search operations on a UITableView below it.

Problem is, when I set up a tap gesture to dismiss the keyboard on touches outside of the UITextField, it seems to cancel out the didSelect method of my TableView cells.

Here's the code I'm currently using in viewDidLoad:

```
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSingleTap:")
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    }
```

How can I set this up so that touches outside of the UITextField dismiss the keyboard, but still allow me to select TableView cells?

Comment: Out of curiosity; Why aren't you using a `UISearchController` with your table view?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement gesture recognizer delegate.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourTableView]) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

This way it won't interfere with touch on your table view to still allow you to select table view.

Answer (score 1):

No need add any gesture to dismiss keyboard on tableview, iOS SDK itself provide one property to dismiss keyboard called **keyboardDismissMode**. we can this property from IB itself, Check below image for your reference.

[image]

Comment: I am on ios 11.2.1. This didnt work. I had to add the tapgesturerecognizer

Answer (score 0):

Not encourage to use tap gesture so much. I ran into a problem with this when it overrides my custom button. I solved it with `XCDFormInputAccessoryView` for iOS. And it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set `cancelsTouchesInView` property of `UITapGestureRecognizer` to true.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("hideKeyboard"))
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: I actually got this to work by doing the opposite, setting cancelsTouchesInView to false